# dd-wrt subnet from network with in a network

Tags: networking, router, routing, dhcp, dd-wrt

I am testing some network configurations. I am trying to create a network within a network for **TESTING PURPOSES ONLY**. Basically the gateway for `ARouter`(made up name for main router) is `192.168.0.1`(for conversation purposes only). Within that working network I have another dd-wrt router as defined as switch. Lets call this `BSwitch`.

I have `Arouter` communicating with `Bswitch`. However I would like to define the lan subnet on port 2 of the switch(`Bswitch`) as 10.x.x.x so...`10.0.0.1.` I would like  this port to have access to the internet but thats it. IP's of `192.168.0.x` from DHCP server of `ARouter` should not be able to ping IP's of `10.0.0.x`.

I have followed this, but I can't seem to change port 2 of `Bswitch` still: http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/VLAN_Detached_Networks_%28Separate_Networks_With_Internet%29

Any help?

Comment: That's normal, since 192.168.0.1/24 and 10.0.0.1/24 is different subnet, you may add a route from `ARouter` and `Brouter` separately to look for each other : details: http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Linking_Subnets_with_Static_Routes

Comment: Not all routers support VLAN. The DD-WRT Wiki mentions that most Broadcomm-based routers do have VLAN support, but Atheros-based ones mostly don't. Is your router one those few that support VLAN?